# Find and save all words between 2 specific phrase in a large text file

Tags: php, html, c, cmd

Im not a programmer or sth i just found this website suitable to ask my question so please try to help me like you are helping a beginner. (however i know a lil bit about c and php and html)

**Here is my problem**

I have saved the source of a web page in eg "source.txt" file, now **i want to find all of the words in the text that are placed between `<h4>` and `</h4>`**. i need a command to open "source.txt" then look for the words between that two phrase and save each word in different line and finally save them in eg "result.exe"

For example i have:

`<h4>Barton Fink</h4></a>what is your name<br /><h4>Flyer123</h4></a>my name is pimp<br /><h4>mr.jaghi</h4></a>LoL<br />`

And i want my output to be:

**Barton Fink**

**Flyer 123**

**mr.jaghi**

sure its easy do it manually in short codes but in my case its a long page and there is more than thousands of those words needed to be leeched

BTW im using windows platform pls show me a way using cmd if possible or if not tell me the easiest way

Comment: Have you got any code showing you attempted this yourself? Were here to assist with code problems. Not write a program for you.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont im sry if im asking wrong question or if its wrong place to ask but there is nowhere else i can think of and its kinda important to me. I hope some genius members of this decent site can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be as follows, using regular expressions in PowerShell.

```
[regex]::Matches((Get-Content source.txt), "<h4>(.+?)</h4>") | foreach{$_.Groups[1].Value} | OUt-File -FilePath "result.txt"
```

Comment: worked like a charm tnx man